# Cannot add User field to printers.conf

Tags: kubuntu, printing

I need to specify a different user name when printing in my enterprise environment; e.g. by setting `User xxxx` in my cups configuration.

I have tried doing `sudo su; service cups stop;` then editing my `printers.conf` file to add `User xxxx` in the options for the printer, and then `service cups start`. However, within a minute or so, the `printers.conf` gets overwritten and the `User` line is removed.

How can I keep this change?

Comment: Make the change through the CUPS administrative interface at `http://localhost:631/`

Comment: Yes, that solved my issue! However, for some reason, the `User` field still is not present in `printers.conf`, but using that interface, I could also add the correct queue, which I also wasn't able to add manually in `printers.conf`.